# converting values between to data domains

Tags: java, server, domain-mapping

I have to write over a hundred integrations between many systems. This integration layer must be able to convert codes. Each system uses codes to represent business types like insurance_type, customer_type, etc. Each of them has a set of valid values. Theses values are not the same from system to system, and may even vary over time.

I start looking for data domain mapping libraries in Java. I didn't found anything suitable. I thought about: CloverETL,Pentaho ETLou GETL​ but they are all way too complex for my need or not maintain.

The goal is to put the conversion rules out of the code so they could evolve over time without the need for a new executable deployment.

I'm looking for a tool, library that would allow me to represent mapping similar to this:

```
{
  "domains" :[
    {
      "name": "type police host",
      "values": [
        {
          "code" : "0001",
          "description":"Habitation",
          "start_date":"2019-06-30",
          "end_date":""},
        {
          "code" : "0002",
          "description":"Automobile",
          "start_date":"2019-06-30",
          "end_date":""}
        ]
    },
    {
      "name": "type police web",
      "values": [
        {
          "code" : "Habitation",
          "description":"Habitation",
          "start_date":"2019-06-30",
          "end_date":""}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "conversions" : [
    {
    "from": "type police host",
    "to": "type police web",
    "rules" : [
      {
        "from": ["0001"],
        "to" : "Habitation",
        "start_date":"2019-06-30",
        "end_date":""},
      {
        "from": [ "0003","0004"],
        "to" : "Deux roues",
        "start_date":"2019-06-30",
        "end_date":""}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From the configuration file above, I would be able to do things like `convertsAsOf("2019-07-10", "type police host", "type police web", "0001")` and it would return `"Habitation"`. Any suggestion of a library that would do it?

Comment: Check out [Jackson ObjectMapping](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial).

Comment: I've seen similar problems solved well with [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org)